# Make a choice with a ComboBox, PyQT

Tags: pyqt

how are you ?

I just to create a programme wherein a propose a choice with Combobox.

For exemple, if you choice a item in a ComboBox, it will be write in a Spinbox.
But my probléme is that, to wirte in a third Spinbox without create a new Combobox.

Hope you understand

Check it out :)

`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import (QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QSpinBox, QComboBox)



class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.spin = QSpinBox(self)
        self.spin2 = QSpinBox(self)
        self.spin3 = QSpinBox(self)

        self.combo = QComboBox(self)
        self.combo2 = QComboBox(self)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.spin)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.spin2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.spin3)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.combo2)

        self.combo.currentIndexChanged['QString'].connect(self.on_combo_changed)
        self.combo2.currentIndexChanged['QString'].connect(self.changed)


        self.data = {"HANDSET1": 5,"HANDSET": 6, "HANDFREE": 10, "CAR KIT": 15, "RSM": 20}
        self.dodo = {"HANDSET1": 44, "HANDSET": 76, "HANDFREE": 1, "CAR KIT": 7, "RSM": 0}
        self.coco = {"HANDSET1": 0, "HANDSET": 7, "HANDFREE": 11, "CAR KIT": 77, "RSM": 10} # How to put this function, without create a other ComboBox ?

        self.combo.addItems(self.data.keys())
        self.combo2.addItems(self.dodo.keys())


    def on_combo_changed(self, txt):
        self.spin.setValue(self.data[unicode(txt)])
    def changed(self, txt):
        self.spin2.setValue(self.coco[unicode(txt)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`

Comment: I think you can't set discrete set of strings (not even discrete set of integers) to a spinbox. Why not use comboBox instead?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. Perhaps you could update your question with a longer explanation of what the code you have written is doing (what do you want your application to do?).

Comment: I this is just a matter of display you should use a QLineEdit (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html) for example.